# Common Table Expressions -- Using a Variable in the Predicate

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've written a common table expression to return hierarchical information and it seems to work without issue if I hard code a value into the `WHERE` statement. If I use a variable (even if the variable contains the same information as the hard coded value), I get the error `The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.`

This is easier shown with a simple example (note, I haven't included the actual code for the CTE just to keep things clearer. If you think it's useful, I can certainly add it).

**This Works**

```
WITH Blder
        AS
        (-- CODE IS HERE )

        SELECT
            *
        FROM Blder as b
        WHERE b.PartNo = 'ABCDE';
```

**This throws the Max Recursion Error**

```
DECLARE @part CHAR(25);
SET @part = 'ABCDE'

WITH Blder
AS
(-- CODE IS HERE )

SELECT
    *
FROM Blder as b
WHERE b.PartNo = @part;
```

Am I missing something silly? Or does the SQL engine handle hardcoded values and parameter values differently in this type of scenario?

Comment: Actual problem looks like with the query used inside the CTE.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly put semicolon at the end of your variable assignment statement

```
SET @part ='ABCDE';
```

Comment: Thanks. I did have a semicolon in the actual code, but I accidentally got rid of it while copying code here.

Answer (score 0):

Your `SELECT` statement is written incorrectly: the SQL Server Query Optimizer is able to optimize away the potential cycle if fed the literal string, but not when it's fed a variable, which uses the plan that developed from the statistics.

SQL Server 2016 improved on the Query Optimizer, so if you could migrate your DB to SQL Server 2016 or newer, either with the DB compatibility level set to 130 or higher (for SQL Server 2016 and up), or have it kept at 100 (for SQL Server 2008) but with `OPTION (USE HINT ('ENABLE_QUERY_OPTIMIZER_HOTFIXES'))` added to the bottom of your `SELECT` statement, you should get the desired result without the max recursion error.

If you are stuck on SQL Server 2008, you could also add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the bottom of your `SELECT` statement to create an ad hoc query plan that would be similar to the one that worked correctly.