# Not able to use variable value inside CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, variables, common-table-expression

I am using a variable value inside a CTE but it is going into an infinite loop and when I hard code the value like 'Food' instead of variable `@ProductSection`, it is executing:

```
DECLARE @ProductSection varchar(100) = (SELECT ProductSection FROM Product WHERE ProductId = 6572);
WITH DirectIndirectProd (ProdId,ReporteeID ,NAME, [Level],[Root])  
  AS  
  (  
    SELECT ProdId,  
      ReporteeID,  
      NAME,  
      0 AS [Level] ,  
      RootHS AS [Root]  
      FROM Product  
      WHERE SECTION_CD = @ProductSection
      UNION ALL  
      SELECT  P1.ProdId,  
      P1.Report,  
      P1.FNAME,   
      [Level] + 1 , d.[Root]  
      FROM Product P1  
      INNER JOIN DirectIndirectProd AS D  
      ON P1.Rpt_PrdID = D.ProdID  
  )
```

Please help me in this query where I am doing wrong to declare variable value?

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Why do you think the variable is the problem?

Comment: @MattM because instead of variable name ProductSection when i gave value 'Food', this query is executing..otherwise it is going to infinite loop..no error

Comment: When you are using a variable and if you add `select @ProductSection` before the CTE, what does it return? Really we need some example sample data + expected results i.e. a [mre]

Comment: Add `where level < 10` to the recursive part of the recursive CTE to see what is happening.

Comment: See if my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72836600/3892044) helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would appear to have cycles in your code.  That can be hard to deal with.  But you can see what is happening by adding something like:

```
where level < 10
```

to see what is happening.

One trivial case would be if `Rpt_PrdID = ProdID`.  However, there are other possibilities as well.

If this is the issue, I would advise you to ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data and desired results.  Setting up a fiddle of some sort is also very helpful for this type of problem.